# Clicking is not working in my dell vostro 3568

Tags: touchpad, 17.04, fingerprint-reader

I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my Dell Vostro 3568 laptop. Neither my left or right click is working. I have also tried mouse setting, but I get nothing from it.

Comment: Have you tried with an external mouse yet? Also, you will need to move your question about finger print security to a new question so we can better help you.

Comment: i have also tried with external mouse but i get same result.